# Override Chrome's new fullscreen API

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, html5

Is there a way to disable the fullscreen API for Chrome, so that Youtube HTML5 videos maximize to the size of the tab, not the screen? I've got a really large screen and having the video at half the screen size is good enough.